# if it's possible to run batch processing on dynamic table in flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql, pyflink, flink-batch

Currently I run multiple varient structured ETL job on the same table by the following steps:

1. sync data from RDBMS to data warehouse continuously.
2. run multiple ETL at different time(data in data warehouse at corresponding timepoint).

If it's possible to share the dynamic table across multiple ETL job at different time, then the first syncing step can be removed.

Comment: Can you clarify the question, preferably by providing a concrete example of what you would like to do? I'm not confident I have correctly interpreted what you are asking.

Comment: @DavidAnderson hi, I made a change to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few options I can think.

1. Use external database like sql or something to load the dynamic config table. This would load table every time your batch job runs.
2. Versioned table is also an option, as you may have explored already.
3. Use [flink queryable state](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/fault-tolerance/queryable_state/). You would need external client to update the state though.

Comment: If use versioned table, how to share a dynamic table across multiple etl job at any time?